# Send email notifications when Airflow dag is timeout

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am using Airflow v2.2.5.
I want to send email notification when a dag is timeout.

So far I am able to send email for task level failure .
[image]
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted should already satisfy your request.

When the `dagrun_timeout` is reached the DAG is marked as failed, hence the `on_failure_callback` is called.

In the callback you can access the `context['reason']` field to check if the failure is due to the timeout or another reason:

```py
dag_timed_out = context['reason'] == 'timed_out'
```

---

Here is a full example:

```py
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

def printx(v):
    print(v)
    with open("/tmp/SO_74153563.log", "a") as f:
        f.write(v + "\n")

def dag_callback(ctx):
    printx("DAG Failure.\nReason: " + ctx['reason'])
    timed_out = ctx['reason'] == 'timed_out'
    printx("Timed out: " + str(timed_out))

def long_running_job():
    printx("Sleeping...")
    sleep(40)
    printx("Sleeped")

with DAG(
    "SO_74153563",
    start_date=datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 2),
    schedule_interval=None,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(seconds = 15),
    on_failure_callback=dag_callback
) as dag:
    task_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task_1",
        python_callable=long_running_job
    )
```

The task sleeps for `40 seconds` while the DAG has a timeout of `15 seconds`, so it will fail. The output will be:

```
DAG Failure.
Reason: timed_out
Timed out: True
```

The only difference from your callback is that now it is defined directly on the DAG.

Comment: There is no context variable "reason" is present in airflow.

Comment: Could you please share some sample code for the same which is working

Comment: @Puja Shaw answer updated with sample code